# Filter for the last loopback adapter in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm writing/editing/hacking a powershell script to add loopback adapters.

Once I've added the new loopback adapter, I need to get a handle on it. I currently do this:

```
$nic = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "Description='Microsoft Loopback Adapter'"
```

But this only works if there aren't currently any loopback adapters. If I already have one, then add another, then this will return the first one. What I want is the *last* (or most recent) one in this list I want to get back the "Microsoft Loopback adapter #2", the time after I want "Microsoft Loopback adapter #3", etc...

```
DHCPEnabled      : False
IPAddress        : {192.168.1.90}
ServiceName      : msloop
Description      : Microsoft Loopback Adapter
Index            : 17

DHCPEnabled      : True
IPAddress        : {169.254.115.94, fe80::bc90:a8ba:b435:735e}
DefaultIPGateway :
DNSDomain        :
ServiceName      : msloop
Description      : Microsoft Loopback Adapter #2
Index            : 18
```

Is this possible in powershell at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your result, I find that filtering on the ServiceName would be more reliable:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "ServiceName='msloop'" | 
Sort-Object Index | 
Select-Object -Last 1
```

Comment: Brilliant - I had no idea that Sort-Object existed, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "Description='Microsoft Loopback Adapter'" | Sort-Object Index -descending | Select-Object -first 1
```

Get all instances where Description is 'Microsoft Loopback Adapter', sort them by Index value descending and select the top one.